# Replace links on page based on location.host and a cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery to rewrite a list of links on the page. If the location.host is NOT the vendor location.host AND the cookie isn't set to a specific value then it locates the links and rewrites them to the alternate values. The code I'm using works great in FF but not in IE7. Please help!

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    // link hider       
    var hostadd = location.host;
    var vendor = '172.29.132.34';
    var localaccess = 'internal.na.internal.com';
    var unlock = 'http://internal.na.internal.com/Learning/Customer_Care/navigation/newhire.html';



    // link rewriter                            
    $(document).ready (
        function style_switcher(){ 
            //if not a vendor or not accessing from lms reroute user to lms
            if (hostadd != vendor && $.cookie("unlockCookie") != unlock){
                var linkData = {
                "https://www.somesite.com":             "https://internalsite.com/something",'../Compliance/something/index.html':'../somethingelse.html'

            };
            $("a").each(function() {
                 var link = this.getAttribute("href");  // use getAttribute to get what was actualy in the page, perhaps not fully qualified
                if (linkData[link]) {
                this.href = linkData[link];
            }
            });
        }
    });     
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly isnt working? Do you get an error, and have you tried using breakpoints to see where it fails?

Comment: I'm not familiar with breakpoints...so no i haven't tried those. I don't get an error...it just doesn't rewrite the links.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, if you insert the links dynamic, is store them in a data attribute like data-orglink="yourlink" which wouldnt be transformed by the browser, then check on that -and if its in the object array - change the href. Do you have access to creating the data attribute?

---

IE7 have problems with internal links, because it puts the host info on, before JS can reach the link..

http://jsfiddle.net/Cvj8C/9/

Will work in all, but IE7. So you need to use full paths if to use JS for this function :(

---

You had some errors in your JS.

But it seems to work fine?

See: http://jsfiddle.net/s4XmP/

or am i missing something? :)

Comment: actually when i open your jsfiddle in IE7 it doesn't work either. hello still routes to https://www.somesite.com

Comment: Its on the if (linkData[link])  it fails.. What is that supposed to do? :)

Comment: it should be looking through all the links on the page to find matches...if it finds a match then it replaces it with the alternate url.